# login ssh then run server through .bat file

Tags: ssh, batch-file, shortcuts, windows-terminal

I am new to command line and I am trying to achieve the following but have no success.

1. Open windows terminal
2. `ssh my-instance-my-user-name -l my-user-name`
3. `cd dev/my_app` (I have 2 app)
4. `npm run dev`
5. redo step 1~4 on the same windows terminal but different tabs.

I only managed to do until #2 which is the following.

this is my .bat file

```
echo off
start wt -M ssh my-instance-my-user-name -l my-user-name
```

Any help is greatly appreciated !

Comment: Maybe my approach is wrong since once I ssh into my instance I would have to do the commands there... any inputs guys?

Comment: Consider adding a bit more detail. IE are you able to run that ssh command from your windows terminal (not in a bat file)? Do you end up getting connected? Does it ask you for a password.

Comment: yes, I already did my initial configuration. All I really need is to automate my manual task. it seems too simple but as I delve into it I find it hard and make me actually think to just focus on my app.